# Set different Number of column for different row in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

how can i set different no. of columns for different rows? i know using less we can set number of columns as per requirement but what if i need to set different number of columns in different rows?

i need to set different grid column numbers for different rows . Please suggest.

```
@gridColumns:             12;
@gridColumnWidth:         60px;
@gridGutterWidth:         20px;
@gridRowWidth:            (@gridColumns * @gridColumnWidth) + (@gridGutterWidth *         (@gridColumns - 1));
```

here grid column i am talking about .

Comment: Can you give us some examples? How many columns in each row do you need? What width (or percentage) are the columns or are they always equal width?

Comment: Suppose in first row I need 10 couln then I second I neeed 5 and in third 12

Comment: Actually I was asked abt this in an interview

Comment: Did you have to use bootstrap? You could have made the base 60 columns wide and use "col-md-6" for 10 columns, "col-md-12" for 5 columns, and "col-md-5" for 12 columns. Though I really doubt that is what they were after...

Comment: no... they wanted to use col-md-1  to fit 10 column in first row ,then 13 column in secong and so on..